# RDTSC equivalent for iOS

Tags: ios, time, arm

I'm looking to do high-precision timing in an iOS app. On an Intel x86 chip, I'd use RDTSC to get timestamps, but I can't do that on an ARM device. Is there an equivalent of RDTSC that can be used from an iOS app?

Comment: Even on x86 chips, the TSC would not be a good choice. It is not a reliable way of timing things, *especially* on a mobile device where power management features are virtually guaranteed to disrupt your timing. There should be an operating system API for this.

Answer (score 4):

There appears to be a clang builtin for this, `__builtin_readcyclecounter()`. On x86, it compiles to `rdtsc`; on ARM64, it compiles to `mrs x0, PMCCNTR_EL0`. On ARM it always returns 0 though. ARM64 is good enough for me though, since 32-bit support was dropped in iOS 11.

Answer (score 1):

For high-precision timing, perhaps you could use mach_absolute_time()

[Technical Q&A QA1398 Mach Absolute Time Units](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1398/_index.html)